# How to parse this json in flutter?

Tags: http, flutter

This Is my Json How can I Fetch this Fetch in Flutter? How Can I Create model For This ?
This Is Json Url [http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key={MY](http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=%7BMY) API}&query=jaipur

Answer (score 0):

you can use this project https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/ or this one https://app.quicktype.io/ and select Dart language to help you create models based on json data

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically parse JSON to Dart classes by using [this](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)

```
  class Weather {
      Request request;
      Location location;
      Current current;
    
      Weather({this.request, this.location, this.current});
    
      Weather.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        request =
            json['request'] != null ? new Request.fromJson(json['request']) : null;
        location = json['location'] != null
            ? new Location.fromJson(json['location'])
            : null;
        current =
            json['current'] != null ? new Current.fromJson(json['current']) : null;
      }
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        if (this.request != null) {
          data['request'] = this.request.toJson();
        }
        if (this.location != null) {
          data['location'] = this.location.toJson();
        }
        if (this.current != null) {
          data['current'] = this.current.toJson();
        }
        return data;
      }
    }
    
    class Request {
      String type;
      String query;
      String language;
      String unit;
    
      Request({this.type, this.query, this.language, this.unit});
    
      Request.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        type = json['type'];
        query = json['query'];
        language = json['language'];
        unit = json['unit'];
      }
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['type'] = this.type;
        data['query'] = this.query;
        data['language'] = this.language;
        data['unit'] = this.unit;
        return data;
      }
    }
    
    class Location {
      String name;
      String country;
      String region;
      String lat;
      String lon;
      String timezoneId;
      String localtime;
      int localtimeEpoch;
      String utcOffset;
    
      Location(
          {this.name,
          this.country,
          this.region,
          this.lat,
          this.lon,
          this.timezoneId,
          this.localtime,
          this.localtimeEpoch,
          this.utcOffset});
    
      Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        name = json['name'];
        country = json['country'];
        region = json['region'];
        lat = json['lat'];
        lon = json['lon'];
        timezoneId = json['timezone_id'];
        localtime = json['localtime'];
        localtimeEpoch = json['localtime_epoch'];
        utcOffset = json['utc_offset'];
      }
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['name'] = this.name;
        data['country'] = this.country;
        data['region'] = this.region;
        data['lat'] = this.lat;
        data['lon'] = this.lon;
        data['timezone_id'] = this.timezoneId;
        data['localtime'] = this.localtime;
        data['localtime_epoch'] = this.localtimeEpoch;
        data['utc_offset'] = this.utcOffset;
        return data;
      }
    }
    
    class Current {
      String observationTime;
      int temperature;
      int weatherCode;
      List<String> weatherIcons;
      List<String> weatherDescriptions;
      int windSpeed;
      int windDegree;
      String windDir;
      int pressure;
      double precip;
      int humidity;
      int cloudcover;
      int feelslike;
      int uvIndex;
      int visibility;
      String isDay;
    
      Current(
          {this.observationTime,
          this.temperature,
          this.weatherCode,
          this.weatherIcons,
          this.weatherDescriptions,
          this.windSpeed,
          this.windDegree,
          this.windDir,
          this.pressure,
          this.precip,
          this.humidity,
          this.cloudcover,
          this.feelslike,
          this.uvIndex,
          this.visibility,
          this.isDay});
    
      Current.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        observationTime = json['observation_time'];
        temperature = json['temperature'];
        weatherCode = json['weather_code'];
        weatherIcons = json['weather_icons'].cast<String>();
        weatherDescriptions = json['weather_descriptions'].cast<String>();
        windSpeed = json['wind_speed'];
        windDegree = json['wind_degree'];
        windDir = json['wind_dir'];
        pressure = json['pressure'];
        precip = json['precip'];
        humidity = json['humidity'];
        cloudcover = json['cloudcover'];
        feelslike = json['feelslike'];
        uvIndex = json['uv_index'];
        visibility = json['visibility'];
        isDay = json['is_day'];
      }
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['observation_time'] = this.observationTime;
        data['temperature'] = this.temperature;
        data['weather_code'] = this.weatherCode;
        data['weather_icons'] = this.weatherIcons;
        data['weather_descriptions'] = this.weatherDescriptions;
        data['wind_speed'] = this.windSpeed;
        data['wind_degree'] = this.windDegree;
        data['wind_dir'] = this.windDir;
        data['pressure'] = this.pressure;
        data['precip'] = this.precip;
        data['humidity'] = this.humidity;
        data['cloudcover'] = this.cloudcover;
        data['feelslike'] = this.feelslike;
        data['uv_index'] = this.uvIndex;
        data['visibility'] = this.visibility;
        data['is_day'] = this.isDay;
        return data;
      }
    }
```

convert json to dart by `Weather.fromJson(json);`

Comment: how can i apply ?? to text?